# JS Calculation assistance

Tags: javascript

I'm having some issues with my code, I'm creating a site to get it to calculate mortgages with down payments of:
3% of the first $25,000
Insures home mortgages requiring a down payment as follows:
3% of the first $25,000
5% of the remainder

The input consists of a SSN and a mortgage amount. I wanted it to print the applicant’s SSN and the amount of down payment required. Reject any applications over $70,000. Don’t forget to validate your input. If the input is not good, and I want it to display an error message and ask for the input data again.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Mortgage Charges</title>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
// Program name: FHA 
// Purpose: print the applicant’s SSN and the amount of down payment required
// Date last modified: 3/29/12
function mortgage() {
    var amtOwed = parseInt(document.frmOne.ssn.value);
    var mortgage = 0;

    if (mortgage <= 25000) {
        amtOwed = 0;
    }
    else if (mortgage >= 5%) {
    }
    alert(amtOwed);
    document.frmOne.mortage.value = amtOwed;
}

window.onload = function() {
    document.frmOne.onsubmit = function(e) {
       mortgage();
       return false;
    };
};

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="frmOne">
Enter your SSN:<input type="text" id="ssn" /><br />
Mortgage amount:<input type="text" id="mortage" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `(mortgage >= 5%) {` wont work for starters .... but what are the other errors ? what happens when you run it ? what errors do you get ? .. i suggest you [start here and read](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide)

Comment: I know you have just registered on here - but you really need to read the FAQ - this is a site for coding assistance - not writing solutions based on your requirements .... i really suggest you take some time to learn JavaScript properly and attempt yourself to do this kinds of calculations - once you have more of an idea come back, demonstrate some real code and ask for specific help

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid I can't fathom your logic. How do you expect this to work?

Let me break down what your current code does:

```
function mortgage() {
    var amtOwed = parseInt(document.frmOne.ssn.value);
    // Get the value from the text box, and convert it to a number. That's good.
    var mortgage = 0;
    // Initialise a variable. Fair enough.

    if (mortgage <= 25000) {
    // You JUST set morgage=0. How can it be anything but less than 25k?
        amtOwed = 0;
        // You are overwriting the value you got from the form with 0
    }
    else if (mortgage >= 5%) {
        // Okay, first of all this else will never be reached, see comment above.
        // Second... 5% of what, exactly? If you want 5% of a number, multiply the number by 0.05
        // Third, what's the point of this block if there's no code in it?
    }
    alert(amtOwed);
    document.frmOne.mortage.value = amtOwed;
}
```

Basically, your code can be simplified to:

```
function morgage() {document.frmOne.mortage.value = 0;}
```

Because that's all it does.

I don't really understand exactly what you're doing, but hopefully explaining what your current attempt is doing will help you to find the answer.

Comment: +1 was just writing an answer very similar to this one !!!! it basically sets the input value to `0` !!!!!

Comment: Insures home mortgages requiring a down payment as follows:
3% of the first $25,000
5% of the remainder

The input consists of a SSN and a mortgage amount. I wanted it to print the applicant’s SSN and the amount of down payment required. Reject any applications over $70,000. Don’t forget to validate your input. If the input is not good, and I want it to display an error message and ask for the input data again.

Comment: Actually I was talking to ManseUK. I'm not here to write your code for you, SO is intended to get help fixing stuff after you've given it your best try. So, take what I've given you here, go back to your editor, and have another go at getting this right yourself. If it still doesn't work, update your question (or create a new one if it's too different) and repeat the process.